# jqplot export image, xaxis not rendering properly

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqplot

I am using JQPlot to generate the graphs, i am converting the graph to image. But in the converted image the xaxis labels are starting from the middle of the graph, instead of beginning. Can anyone knows about this issue and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced this type of issue. Make sure that The placeholder where you plot your graph  don't have `text-align:center` css property. Otherwise It will start plotting x axis from middle instead of starting point.